# Filter the results using n-hibernate via matching with another Db table

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

I have already written Hbn & code to fetch the users from db.

with following info

userid, name,email,phone

now we have new requirement in which new table has been created with following fields

Table 1

- userid -- foreign key to above user table
- workinglocation
- WorkingStatusId

table 2

- WorkingStatusId
- workingstatus

filter criteria is workinglocation and workingstatus

i can not change my existing code.

either i have to write new hbn file and write the code

or should i fetch the data using earlier created hbn and filter it

Please suggest me with the code using linq etc (if possible)

Answer (score 2):

either add a collection of `Workplaces` or whatever to the user and map it then it would be easy to query

```
from u in session.Query<User>()
from w in u.Workplaces
where ...
select u;
```

or filter with a correlated subquery after mapping Workplaces